# importation datetime problem with pandas.read_csv(...)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I downloaded a csv file from *yahoo finance*.

I have a problem with the dates when I import the file with the command :

```
pd_index=pd.read_csv("path/yahoo.csv",parse_dates=["Date"])
```

The output of this commands is :

```
     Date         Open    ...        Adj Close     Volume
0  2018-03-12  25779.57031    ...      25826.42969  388480000
1  2018-04-12  25752.56055    ...      25027.07031  418900000
2  2018-06-12  24737.41992    ...      24947.66992  471690000
3  2018-07-12  24918.82031    ...      24388.94922  398230000
4  2018-10-12  24360.94922    ...      24423.25977  389690000
5  2018-11-12  24719.91016    ...      24370.24023  342960000
6  2018-12-12  24509.08984    ...      24527.26953  344330000
7  2018-12-13  24575.85938    ...      24597.38086  299970000
8  2018-12-14  24408.03906    ...      24100.50977  416940000
```

As you can see in the output, the "format" of every output of the "Date" column are :

```
    Date        
0  2018-03-12  year-day-month
1  2018-04-12  year-day-month
2  2018-06-12  year-day-month
3  2018-07-12  year-day-month
4  2018-10-12  year-day-month
5  2018-11-12  year-day-month
6  2018-12-12  year-month-day
7  2018-12-13  year-month-day
8  2018-12-14  year-month-day
```

As you can see, since the line 6 there is a change in the order. I don't understand why because in the csv file [csv file from yahoo finance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYnsU.png) the order is always constant (day-month-year)

Someone knows where I made a mistake and why my code reacts like this?

Comment: Try ```pd.read_csv("path/yahoo.csv", parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)```

Comment: @jwalton3141  Thank you a lot!! it gives me the good result!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: The parser seems to be interpreting the dates as MM.DD.YY until it hits the line where it encounters 13 in the slot it previously assigned as the month.

Comment: @tshimkus good spot. But you mean YY.DD.MM no?

Comment: @jwalton3141 In the image of the CSV file the format is DD.MM.YY

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn't even spotted the link to the image! Another good spot!